# wizard that create code in multiple programming languages

Tags: programming-languages, wizard

as part of our application i need to build component that will output code in php and asp 
that have the same functionality ( and maybe latter jsp ) .
how can i design this kind of component to be generic as possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be able to create a parse tree out of all input languages.

For each output language, you will need to create a set of tree transforming grammar.

You may also require a runtime library to help translate routines that are not available in your output language.

Comment: The input will be GUI not some language i need to parse

Answer (score 1):

I would personally go with the **Strategy Pattern**.  You could have a master code maker class and instantiate it with a strategy.

PHPCodeStrategy
ASPCodeStrategy

Then each would have a method called execute maybe.  Bu then you could add further strategies down the line and extend your application.

Andrew